How to fix a size for every resolution on MFC windows
I have a C++ application that uses MFC window objects.
I have the following situation:
I need the UI elements remain the same doesnt matter what resolution and what DPI is.
But I'd need some kind of global solution that would upscale and downscale automatically all the objects, fonts, images, bmps within this MFC window.

This would have to deal with fundamental in MFC engine, not talking about it to be responsive, but talking about the elements to automatically auto scale depending on the resolution and DPI, BUT based on a initial set, e.g. 96DPI and 1980x1024 resolution.

another feature over this: if I change the resolution when the program is opened it would have to change all forms to fit on new resolution.


Is this kind of feature available on this framework?

Is this kind of feature available on this framework? AFAIK, there is not anything like it. The closest things you can do: 1. Handle WM_SIZE(); 2. For the controls rearrangement, you can use Dynamic layouts, but be advised that is a very limited feature.
